# Why does Swift 2.0 print out last element in array instead of all elements?

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, swift2

I'm trying to print out all the elements in this array, and when I display it, it only prints out Pickup laundry.

```
var todo = ["Return Calls", "Write blog", "Cook Dinner", "Pickup laundry"]

for element in todo {
print(element)
}
```

I'm not sure why this is wrong...

Comment: Is that your real code?

Comment: It works as advertised for me. It printed all four items.

Comment: You might need to delete xcode preferences using terminal type defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm in a playground? Does that have different preferences?

Comment: Never mind I got my answer, thanks to all who answered

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code and pasted it into an app. I ran the app. I saw this in the console:

```
Return Calls
Write blog
Cook Dinner
Pickup laundry
```

So I conclude that either you are lying — that is not your code, or that is not what is printed — or you don't know how to test (e.g. you don't know how to read the console or you're in a playground and you don't understand where the console is).

Comment: I'm not lying (why would I be??), I am in a playground  and I tried opening the console in assistant editor but it does not open. Does the playground have different preferences than coding without the playground?